# Right way to detect browser and stop user from using page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Ok, I want to allow user to be able to use the page only when browser is Chrome or IE8-9.
I doing so from code behind as you can see. And also trying to set viability of main div to none.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
        if (browser.Type.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("ie"))
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(browser.Version) < 8 || Convert.ToDecimal(browser.Version) > 9)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>alert('Your browser is not supported. Please use Chrome or IE7,IE8,IE9');</script>", false);
                pagecontainer.Attributes["style"] = "visible:none";
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (!browser.Type.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("chrome"))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>alert('Your browser is not supported. Please use Chrome or IE7,IE8,IE9');}</script>", false);
            pagecontainer.Attributes["style"] = "visible:none";
            return;
        }
//blah blah       
}


<div id="pagecontainer" runat="server" >Page Content Goes Here</div>
```

But it does not seem to be hiding the div.
I know I can always redirect user to a warning page or something but lets say I do not want to do so. What are my alternatives?

Comment: where is pagecontainer variable defined?

Comment: pagecontainer is the id of the div.

Comment: With `runat="server"` you can do `pagecontainer.Visible = false;` also.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I am having a blonde moment although I am not blonde lol.
But are there any other alternatives? Just for information. And btw Scriptmanager does not seem to appearing on the screen. Any ideas why?

Comment: why would you want to do this? You cannot do this reliably by the way, as users can fake their user agents in any browser (the user agent string is where you get the information, which browser the user is using)

Comment: I want to do this because we have not been able to test our page on other browsers of some reason. It might or might not work properly on other browsers. Also design might get distorted too.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

> ```
> pagecontainer.Attributes["style"] = "visible:none";
> ```

and use this one instead:

> ```
> pagecontainer.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
> ```